# How to set timer using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a timer through javascript.I made a textbox where the user will give the value suppose 5,I want to generate a javascript counter which will count according to the user input and it will count by seconds.Suppose user will give 5 then after completion of 5 sec an alert will be generated that the count down has been stopped.I want like this..How shall I make that?please give some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the setTimeout() function.
Trigger a javascript function on some event - eg., the onBlur of that text box or onClick of some button.

```
function waitAndAlert(){

var timeToWait = document.getElementById(the_textbox_id).value;
setTimeout(function(){alert("Thanks for waiting")},timeToWait*1000);

}
```

`setTimeout` is more relevant than `setInterval` since the first method just waits for a delay and executes a logic, whereas the second function is meant for repeating a logic on periodic intervals.

**Update:**
To update the user about the progress, you can use the approach suggested by @Prateek  or @Kristof Feys below. However, the sample below uses a combination of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

```
<script>
var count;
var countDown;
var intervalHandl;
function startcounting(){
    count = document.getElementById('countlimit').value;
    countDown = parseInt(count);
    var timer = count*1000;
    intervalHandl = setInterval(function(){setCountdown()},1000); //trigger the periodic update
    setTimeout(function(){showMsg()},timer);

}

function setCountdown(){
    var note = document.getElementById('note');
    note.innerHTML="Countdown: "+countDown;
    countDown--;
}

function showMsg(){
    var note = document.getElementById('note');
    clearInterval(intervalHandl); //stops the periodic update before...
    note.innerHTML="Countdown Over!! "; //...informing the user that the countdown is over
}
</script>
```

Comment: one more thing the timer will display the counter..example if user gives 5.then the user will see on the screen an countdown like 5 4 3 2 1 and then alert will show.

Comment: Check the update. Hope this answers your additional question..

Answer (score 0):

this code will make your timer. Yous should put the 2 top lines, in the event that gets triggered when the seconds are filled in by the user

```
//THESE 2 LINES ARE FOR IN THE EVENT
var count=document.getElementById('SecondsInput').value;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //run it every 1 second



function timer()
{
  count-=1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     window.alert("done!");
  }

  //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=30;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
 count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
   //counter ended, do something here
   return;
  }
}
```

Where you want the seconds to appear. Then insert the following line in your timer() function, so it looks like this:

```
function timer()
{
 count=count-1;
 if (count <= 0)
 {
  return;
 }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
 }
```

Timer appear in a paragraph.

```
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here for every second

var rem=document.getElementById("id").value;
if (rem==0)
alert("timeup");
rem=rem-1000;
document.getElementById("hidden_id").value=rem;//create a hidden field of time counter
}, 1000);

<input id="id" type="text" value="">counter_in_millis</input>
<input id="hidden_id" type="hidden" value=""></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like so :

```
<input></input><button>start</button>
```

Javascript :

```
onload = function () {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
        button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    button.onclick = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('too late...');
        }, input.value * 1000);
    }
};
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/KgBF5/.